# Ordering posts by custom fields (Date)

Tags: custom-field

I have posts with TWO custom fields

`Data_START` : **2018-02-20**

`Data_END`: **2018-02-22**

This code make in order all posts by `Data_END`, and that ok.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse183601_filter_category_query' );
    function wpse183601_filter_category_query( $query ) {
        // only modify front-end category archive pages
        if( is_category() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page','6' );
            $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key','Date_END' );
            $query->set( 'order','DESC' );
        }
    }
```

But exist one little problem.

If I add a new post with data like this:

`Data_START` : **2018-02-20**

`Data_END:` **2018-02-19**

This new post appear after all sorted posts by `Data_END` !

Because he have `Data_END` less previous posts..

So how can I do to make it for first ?

Example: (how it works for this moment)

**Loading.....**

> 2018-02-20 - 2018-02-25
>
> 2018-02-20 - 2018-02-24
>
> 2018-01-20 - 2018-02-23
>
> 2018-01-20 - 2018-02-22

It's okay, but not for me !

I want to see for first `Data_END` **LESS** like this :

> 2018-01-20 - 2018-01-22
>
> 2018-01-20 - 2018-02-23
>
> 2018-02-20 - 2018-02-24
>
> 2018-02-20 - 2018-02-25

So.. I can solve this problem, if I set `ASC` instead `DESC`, but, all ordered post by `Data_END` appear in the END of all others posts (in the end of pagination...)

Problem is I don't know how to do this..

Comment: try order = 'DESC' ? you have DES. if that doesn't work there's a few different ways to specify ordering by meta value so i can go through one of them.

Comment: Topic update. pls see it

Comment: Have a look at the last example on [WP_Query Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), scroll down to **'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's**

Comment: It's a good idea, but it not works.. because post have also different post_date too

Comment: Your question says nothing about post_date, how is that related and why is it a problem?

Comment: This is my mistake, post_date is not related to this problem.